# How can I use Html.TextAreaFor() methods in my custom HtmlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 2 website and right now, I have ugly spaghetti code in my view which I would like to make into a custom HtmlHelper. The current code in the view is :

```
            <%switch (Model.fiFieldTypeID) %>
            <%
            {
                case 1: // Text area
                    Response.Write(Html.Encode(Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.fiStrValue)));
                    Response.Write(Html.Encode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fiStrValue)));
                    break;
                case 2: // Text box
                    Response.Write( Html.Encode(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fiStrValue)));
                    Response.Write( Html.Encode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fiStrValue)));
                    break;
etc....
```

I was trying to encapsulate this code into a neat little HtmlHelper. This is how I started:

```
public class FormHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetStreamFieldEditor(this HtmlHelper html, FieldInstance field)
    {
        string output = "";
        switch (field.fiFieldTypeID)
        {
            case 1: // Text area
                output += html.TextAreaFor(field=> field.fiStrValue).ToString();
etc....
```

I know my lamda is wrong... but my bigger concern is that `TextAreaFor` is not available as a method. However, plain old `TextArea` is available. I don't want to use `TextArea` because I need to preserve my model binding. How can I use `TextAreaFor`, `TextBoxFor`, etc, in my custom html helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static class FormHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetStreamFieldEditor(
        this HtmlHelper<YourModelType> html)
    {
        var model = html.ViewData.Model;
        if (model.fiFieldTypeID == 1)
        {
            return html.TextAreaFor(x => x.fiStrValue);
        }
        return html.TextBoxFor(x => x.fiStrValue);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<%: Html.GetStreamFieldEditor() %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.fiStrValue) %>
```

Comment: Interesting, this looks waaaay better than what I was doing. I completely forgot about including the model type in the HtmlHelper parameter: `this HtmlHelper<FieldInstance> html`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Add `using System.Web.Mvc.Html`.</strike>
**EDIT**: Make sure you're referencing System.Web.Mvc.dll v2.0 or higher.

To fix the lambda, you need to manually generate an expression tree using `System.Linq.Expressions`.

Comment: I'm using System.Web.Mvc,Html already. TextAreaFor is still not available.

Comment: @quakkels: Check the DLL version.